# SQL combine two records based on one value

Tags: sql

**Update - work done in SQL-92**
I work in SQL reporting tool and trying to combine two records into one. Let's say there as some duplicates were time got split into two values and hence the duplication. Basically any values that are not duplicated should be added

```
wo---text---time---value 
1----test---5------1
1----test---2------a
3----aaaa---3------1
4----bbbb---4------2
```

Results

```
wo---text---time----value
1----test---7--------1a
3----aaaa---3--------1
4----bbbb---4--------2
```

I tried: 
SELECT ....
FROM ....

GROUP BY wo SUM (time) but that did not even work.

Comment: You need to tell us the DB your using.

Comment: Just edited my query.

Comment: You mean that the solution must be not related  to a specific database???

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: If line 2 value was 2 instead of a, would you expect the combined result to be 12 or 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just two values, you can do:

```
select wo, text, sum(time) as time, concat(min(value), max(value)) as value
from t
group by wo, text;
```

This uses the fact that the standard representation of `1` has a value less than `a`.

Most databases support string aggregation of some sort (`group_concat()`, `listagg()`, and `string_agg()` are typical functions).  You can use one of these for a more general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Set-up:

```
create table so48345659a
(
    wo     integer,
    text   varchar(4),
    time   integer,
    value  varchar(2)
);

create table so48345659b
(
    wo     integer,
    text   varchar(4),
    time   integer,
    value  varchar(2)
);

insert into so48345659a (wo, text, time, value) values (1, 'test', 5, '1');
insert into so48345659a (wo, text, time, value) values (1, 'test', 2, 'a');
insert into so48345659a (wo, text, time, value) values (3, 'aaaa', 3, '1');
insert into so48345659a (wo, text, time, value) values (4, 'bbbb', 4, '2');

insert into so48345659b (wo, text, time, value) values (1, 'test', 7, '1a');
insert into so48345659b (wo, text, time, value) values (3, 'aaaa', 3, '1');
insert into so48345659b (wo, text, time, value) values (4, 'bbbb', 4, '2');
```

Union, by default removes duplicates

```
select wo, text, time, value from so48345659a
union
select wo, text, time, value from so48345659b;
```

Result:

```
 wo | text | time | value 
----+------+------+-------
  1 | test |    7 | 1a
  1 | test |    2 | a
  3 | aaaa |    3 | 1
  1 | test |    5 | 1
  4 | bbbb |    4 | 2
(5 rows)
```

So  now run sum on the union

```
select
    wo,
    sum(time) as total_time
from
    (
        select wo, text, time, value from so48345659a
        union
        select wo, text, time, value from so48345659b
    ) x
group by
    wo;
```

Result:

```
 wo | total_time 
----+------------
  3 |          3
  1 |         14
  4 |          4
(3 rows)
```

---

From your supplementary question (22-Jan-2017), I guess you mean that you have one table that contains duplicate rows.  Is that right?

If so, it might look like this:

```
select * from so48345659c;
 wo | text | time | value 
----+------+------+-------
  1 | test |    5 | 1
  1 | test |    2 | a
  3 | aaaa |    3 | 1
  4 | bbbb |    4 | 2
  1 | test |    7 | 1a
  3 | aaaa |    3 | 1
  4 | bbbb |    4 | 2
(7 rows)
```

So then you get the sum of the times, ignoring duplicate rows, like this:

```
select
    wo,
    sum(time) as total_time
from
    (
        select distinct wo, text, time, value from so48345659c
    ) x
group by
    wo;

 wo | total_time 
----+------------
  3 |          3
  1 |         14
  4 |          4
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Hi, how about the situation i have got only one table (for example so48345659a)?